# Looping over for loop inside another for loop in Django

Tags: django, templates

First see my code please :

My model :

```
class review_product_individual(models.Model):

 product_id  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 product_star = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 product_review_message = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
 product_reviewed_by = models.CharField(max_length=30)
 product_review_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

In views :

```
product_review = review_product_individual.objects.filter(product_id = productID).order_by('-product_review_date')
```

Here product_star will contain 1 to 5 rating and stored as char. Now what I want to do is this I will access each  product_review object in Django template in for loop and inside the for loop I will iterate product_review.product_star times.please see the template code here :`

```
                {% for product_review in product_review %}
            <li>
                <div class="review-heading">
                    <h5 class="name">{{product_review.product_reviewed_by}}</h5>
                    <p class="date">27 DEC 2018, 8:0 PM</p>
                    <div class="review-rating">
                    {% for i in product_review.product_star %}

                        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

                    {% endfor %}


                        <i class="fa fa-star-o empty"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="review-body">
                    <p>{{product_review.product_review_message}}</p>
                </div>
            </li>

            {% endfor %}
```

But only one star is printing as the value of {{product_review.product_star}} =3
I want 3 stars. I could not do in views because product_review contains many objects. So how can I do it ?

Comment: Well you iterate over the number 3, you can not iterate over a number.

Comment: Can you specify why you use  a `CharField` here instead of an `IntegerField`?

Comment: I have tried to convert it to integer. But it says int object not iterable,

Comment: yes, but you are here solving two different problems. A model should not be aware of the templates in which it is used, you should model things first of all consistently, and then worry about templates.

Answer (score 1):

I find it weird that you store the rating as a `CharField` (so a string), instead of using an `IntegerField`, with an `IntegerField`, you can calculate sums, averages, order elements numerically (not lexicographically), etc.

So I would advice you to use an `IntegerField` instead:

```
class ReviewProductIndividual(models.Model):
    product_id  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_star = models.IntegerField()
    product_review_message = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    product_reviewed_by = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    product_review_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

So now we can store ratings with a numerical rating.

Next your problem with the template is that you *iterate over a string*. If you iterate over a string, you iterate over its characters. So that means that if you stored `'5'`, it will iterate *once*: and the iterator will obtain the character `5`. But you want to iterate five times.

What you can do is for example define a `{% range ... %}` tag, like [this snippet does](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/779/). We can for example create a package (with an `__init__.py` file) in **`appname/templatetags/range.py`** (and thus add an empty file **`appname/templatetags/__init__.py`**):

> ```
> from django.template import Library, Node, TemplateSyntaxError
>
> register = Library()
>
> class RangeNode(Node):
>
>     def __init__(self, num, context_name):
>         self.num = Variable(num)
>         self.context_name = context_name
>
>     def render(self, context):
>         context[self.context_name] = range(int(self.num.resolve(context)))
>         return ""
>
> @register.tag
> def num_range(parser, token):
>     """
>     Takes a number and iterates and returns a range (list) that can be 
>     iterated through in templates
>
>     Syntax:
>     {% num_range 5 as some_range %}
>
>     {% for i in some_range %}
>       {{ i }}: Something I want to repeat\n
>     {% endfor %}
>
>     Produces:
>     0: Something I want to repeat 
>     1: Something I want to repeat 
>     2: Something I want to repeat 
>     3: Something I want to repeat 
>     4: Something I want to repeat
>     """
>     try:
>         fnctn, num, trash, context_name = token.split_contents()
>     except ValueError:
>         raise TemplateSyntaxError, "%s takes the syntax %s number_to_iterate\
>             as context_variable" % (fnctn, fnctn)
>     if not trash == 'as':
>         raise TemplateSyntaxError, "%s takes the syntax %s number_to_iterate\
>             as context_variable" % (fnctn, fnctn)
>     return RangeNode(num, context_name)
> ```

Note that this is a slighly modified version (updated with the comment in the snippet).

Now we can use this `{% num_range ... %}` tag:

```
{% for product_review in product_review %}
<li>
    <div class="review-heading">
        <h5 class="name">{{product_review.product_reviewed_by}}</h5>
        <p class="date">27 DEC 2018, 8:0 PM</p>
        <div class="review-rating">
        {% num_range product_review.product_star as star_range %}
        {% for _ in star_range %}

            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

        {% endfor %}


            <i class="fa fa-star-o empty"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review-body">
        <p>{{product_review.product_review_message}}</p>
    </div>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing the code. Going to give a try. :)

Comment: @Yunus: well it is possible some details are not entirely correct (since it is hard to solve a problem with a limited amount of information). In that case please edit your question with the errors you are still facing.